# PrimeNG Treetable: Alternating row colors

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeNG tree table for angular4 and I am trying to style it that odd and even rows has different colors. I am able to do it but only for root rows, when you expand the rows it will get the row color of it's parent.

I also checked the markup produced in html but there's no class that indicates if a row is odd or even.

How exactly do we do it?

Comment: Same issue with me. Did not find any solution. If you have already got the solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

A year has passed and in the new version it's as easy as using the normal `nth-child` on the rows:

```
.ui-treetable-table {
  tbody {
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background: #e9ecef;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are a few issues with the treetable in primeNG. Since it is a very recent component.

Prime Team has declared that they would be reimplementing the treetable in their latest milestone.
Below is the ticket: 
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4813

And they certainly would be taking care of this issue, since they have included my ticket in the milestone (which I created for the same issue): 
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4774